# How can I make it so the opague style only affects the outer element and not the inner element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the outer element have an opaque affect and have the inner element remain the same. I tried using important but that didn't work. Here is my code

```
<h1 id="outer"><div id="inner">Planet</div></h1>
```

and the css

```
#outer{
         background-color: black;
         opacity: 0.8;
     }

     #inner{
         color: white !important;
     }
```

What's the correct syntax for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use rgba instead, you can change the opacity of the outer background colour using the alpha channel

```
#outer{
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

to learn more about rgba [check this out](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: That did the trick Tried to accept your answer but I have to wait 8 minutes